# JSF to set style in stylesheets?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, stylesheet

So I'm trying to create a webpage with customizable style for each user. You can save style options as strings in a JSF bean property and access them in inline style attributes, or `<style>` tags within a webpage very easily, but who uses inline/onpage styling anymore?

Is there any way to forward these properties from a JSF (2.0) bean to my stylesheet or am I required to simply add `<style>` blocks to the pages I wish to be customizable?

EDIT: I guess I could make a function to write these properties to a stylesheet, making one for each user, but this is obviously not preferred.

Comment: You can use EL expressions in your css if you use the `h:outputStylesheet` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For full customization, you could save stylesheets for all the changeable elements and their style options and reference these with your bean properties.

Since that is quite a bit of stylesheets though, you could just define your own style schemes and give the users a choice between these pre-defined stylesheets. This doesn't exactly answer your question but would save a lot of work

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what your functionality is, but one option would be ->

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="#{userBean.styleSheetName}"  />
```

Where the "UserBean" had names of sheets.

Alternatively you could just output the stylesheet (as you said) inbetween the style tags. If you wanted to go nuts you could write a servlet that read the user's session and generated a cached stylesheet.

I would definitely go the servlet route for the functionality you're suggesting, but if it is just a "set" of stylesheets the users have access to, I would probably use a simple dynamic property as per the first example.

Comment: I should say that you would obviously place those in resources/css/sheetName.css